# Did Bellatrix really love her husband?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, love

In harry potter, Bellatrix is one of Voldemort's most beloved and loyal Death Eaters. Voldemort even trained her himself.

> "trained in the dark arts by the dark lord himself"

She is married to Rodolphus Lestrange, but (as far as I can find) never shows any affection towards him. She shows much more interest in Voldemort. one of the best examples I can find of this is :

> " 'My Lord... my Lord...'
>
> It was Bellatrix's voice, and she spoke as if to a lover."

and then:

> "Voldemort seemed to be getting to his feet. Various Death Eaters were hurrying away from him, returning to the crowd lining the clearing. Bellatrix alone remained behind, kneeling beside Voldemort."

and a few lines later:

> " 'My Lord, let me. . .'
>
> 'I do not require assistance," said Voldemort coldly, and though he could not see it, Harry pictured Bellatrix withdrawing a helpful hand. "The boy... Is he dead?' "

So, did Bellatrix really love her husband, who she shows no affection to (that I can find), or does she truly love Voldemort?

Comment: Im asking if Bellatrix loved her husband at all, not if she loved Voldemort. my evidence for it was that she seems to have more affection for Voldemort. its a different question.

Comment: Duplicates are based on the answers as well as the question; alexwlchan's answer to the linked question is basically identical to my answer below

Comment: the answer is the same, but not entirely. the answer for the other question was "but her true love was always Voldemort." and the answer for my question was "She took a pureblood husband, because that was what was expected of her" different parts of the same answer answer our questions.

Comment: Another good example: *She sat beside her sister, as unlike her in looks, with her dark hair and heavily lidded eyes, as she was in bearing and demeanour; where Narcissa sat rigid and impassive, Bellatrix leaned toward Voldemort, for **mere words could not demonstrate her longing for closeness**.*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Bellatrix only loved Voldemort; her marriage was to meet the expectations of her family and pureblood culture.

Rowling answered this in a 2007 live webchat, [transcript on The Leaky Cauldron](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/7/30/j-k-rowling-web-chat-transcript/):

> **Isabel:** Did bellatrix ever love her husband, or did she have love only for voldemort
>
> **Rowling:** She took a pureblood husband, because that was what was expected of her, but her true love was always Voldemort.

Comment: +1. It's always fun when a question gets asked on this site, and it turns out that the creator has been asked *that exact question*.  Something so satisfyingly definitive about the answer.

Comment: @Nerrolken Easy rep too ;) Though there's always the trouble that someone else has usually asked it

Comment: @JasonBaker Hey now, save some rep for the less fortunate. :P