# Did Voldemort love Bellatrix, after all?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, the-cursed-child

Voldemort was said to have been incapable of love, in the Harry Potter series. His own birth was the result of a love potion that Merope had used on his father, Tom Riddle Senior. So, it is surprising that the Dark Lord had a child with Bellatrix willingly.

I remember reading his reaction when Bellatrix was killed by Molly Weasley.

> "... Voldemort's fury at the fall of his last, best lieutenant exploded with the force of a bomb. Voldemort raised his wand and directed it at Molly Weasley."

So, did he love her?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/149345/why-did-voldemort-choose-bellatrix-lestrange-for-this-very-important-task

Comment: Voldemort did not love, at all. We have a number of questions about this, in addition to the linked dupe: [Did Voldemort love his mother? (duplicate)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/151145/31394), [Did Merope's love potion have anything to do with the fact that Voldemort doesn't love?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/41094/31394), and from the other side [Did Bellatrix Lestrange have any affection towards Voldemort?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/63427/31394), [Did Bellatrix really love her husband? (duplicate)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/87680/31394)

Answer (score 2):

### The Dark Lord did not love Bellatrix, she was simply a means to an end.

Voldemort may have wanted a child to preserve the Slytherin bloodline, as he was the last living descendant. We know that he was the descendant of Salazar Slytherin through the Gaunts. His grandfather was Marvolo Gaunt. We know that Voldemort had strong thoughts on blood purity, even if he was a halfblood himself.

Bellatrix Lestrange was his most loyal servant, and she was a pureblood as well. Bellatrix must have been thrilled to bear Voldemort's child.

> “I was and am the Dark Lord’s most loyal servant. I learned the Dark
>   Arts from him, and I know spells of such power that you, pathetic
>   little boy, can never hope to compete”

Voldemort has demonstrated that he valued Bellatrix more than any other Death Eater. Interestingly, while escaping from the Ministry of Magic after his duel with Dumbledore, he took Bellatrix along with him, and then disapparated. It is notable that he did not do this for any of his other Death Eaters, such as Lucius Malfoy, who was caught and imprisoned.

> “He was there!” shouted a scarlet-robed man with a ponytail, who was
>   pointing at a pile of golden rubble on the other side of the hall,
>   where Bellatrix had lain trapped only moments before. “I saw him, Mr.
>   Fudge, I swear it was You-Know-Who, he grabbed a woman and
>   Disapparated!”

However, it would be quite erroneous to say that Voldemort had love for Bellatrix, since she feared him too much for that to be the case. She is terrified, when she realizes that the prophecy had been smashed, fearing punishment from the Dark Lord.

> “Your dear old mate Voldemort knows it’s gone! He’s not going to be
>   happy with you, is he?” “What? What do you mean?” she cried, and for
>   the first time there was fear in her voice. “No!” she screamed. “It
>   isn’t true, you’re lying! MASTER, I TRIED, I TRIED - DO NOT PUNISH ME”

Therefore, Bellatrix Lestrange was probably just a means to an end, as far as the Dark Lord was concerned.